# Using Timber and Shopify, how can I update the cart preview?

Tags: ajax, shopify, cart, timber

I’m using [Timber](https://shopify.github.io/Timber/) in a Shopify theme.

I have a `POST` request to `/cart/add` on a custom page. The item is added to the cart properly but in my callback, I need to update the cart preview (`ajax-cart-template.liquid`).

I see that a function already exists in `ajax-cart.js` to do this, where a Handlebars template is rendered in the private function, `buildCart()`.

I could duplicate the code in the `buildCart()` function and put it in my callback, but that is obviously redundant. Am I able to somehow call `buildCart()` outside of that scope?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65108306/using-timber-and-shopify-how-can-i-add-meta-fields-on-the-ajax-mini-cart-of-tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a tiny bit of customization this should be doable.

First, make `buildCart` a public method by adding `build: buildCart` to:

```
module = {
  init: init,
  load: loadCart,
  build: buildCart
};
```

As I write this I realize `loadCart` is never used publically. Oops. I think my idea here was that if someone wanted to rebuild the cart, they'd call this `ajaxCart.loadCart()` and it would get the data and build it out.

Since you already have the cart, you can instead do `ajaxCart.build(cart_object)` and you're good to go.

Comment: This worked. I just realized that I actually wanted the `cartUpdateCallback()` function and not `buildCart()`, because that function calls both `buildCart()` and `updateCountPrice()`, which updates the cart template AND the number of items in the cart. Simply adding `cartUpdateCallback()` to the `module` object allowed me to use it on my custom page. Thanks!