# Using Timber and Shopify, how can I add meta fields on the ajax mini cart of timber?

Tags: ajax, shopify, cart, timber, shopify-template

I’m using [Timber](https://github.com/Shopify/Timber) in a Shopify theme.

I would look to add meta fields of the product on the cart.
[Cart screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVmeo.png)

The metafields are showing on product i would like to show that on Ajax mini cart too. [product page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGd57.png)

[js code here](https://github.com/Shopify/Timber/blob/master/assets/ajax-cart.js.liquid)

Let me know if its possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a [few examples](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/metafield#examples) on how you may access a product's metafields.

In the cart page though, because you don't have a direct access to the product object, you should first get access to the product object via the `[line_item][2]` object to be able to access the `metafields`, example:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {{ item.product.metafields.key }}
{% endfor %}
```

And that should do the trick!